# Basic4android - Jsonparser

Tags: basic4android

I have json format like below :

```
{"response":[{Pasien={id=24, name=Erren}, Detailtransaksi=[], Upk={name=Poli Umum}, Pendaftaran={antrian=1, id=1, user_id=9, modified=2015-03-01 14:08:46, keterangan=demam tinggi, pasien_id=24}},
 {Pasien={id=21, name=Lulu Batam}, Detailtransaksi=[], Upk={name=Poli Umum}, Pendaftaran={antrian=2, id=2, user_id=9, modified=2015-03-01 14:09:05, keterangan=kantong kering akut, pasien_id=21}}
]}
```

but I don't know,how to take the array data into the list.

Comment: It's not a valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: i get this format from cakePHP

Answer (score 0):

I tried to tell each symbole what does mean. You must use

```
 Dim j as Json: j.Initialize(string)
 Dim m as Map = j.NextObject()
 Dim l as List = m.Get("response")
 Dim m2 as Map = l.Get(0)
 Dim m3 as Map = m2.Get("Pasien")
 Dim id as Integer = m3.Get("id")
 Dim l2 as List = m3.Get("Detailtransaksi") 'but it has not child element
```

these lines telling to reach data from json.

I hope these tips enough for you.

```html
{  => this mean it is a json object. you must take this to Map by nextObject       

'response':[   => this mean it is a list! you must take this element to List by nextArray
      {        => after take all data to list, get every element from list to Map
         Pasien={   => get "Pasien" value from Map with own key to new Map
                  id=24,   
                  name=Erren
                }, 
         Detailtransaksi=[], 
         Upk={
               name=Poli Umum
             }, 
         Pendaftaran={
                       antrian=1, 
                       id=1, 
                       user_id=9, 
                       modified=2015-03-01 14:08:46,
                       keterangan=demam tinggi, pasien_id=24
                     }
       },

       {
          Pasien={
                    id=21, 
                    name=Lulu Batam
                  }, 
          Detailtransaksi=[],
          Upk={
                name=Poli Umum
              },
          Pendaftaran={
                        antrian=2,
                        id=2, 
                        user_id=9,
                        modified=2015-03-01 14:09:05,
                        keterangan=kantong kering akut, 
                        pasien_id=21
                       }
         }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONParser class.
First you should add the JSON library to your project, then declare a JSONParser variable and initialize it with your JSON text.

Now you can use the following two methods to get the result: 
parser.NextArray As List (when there are more than one element in JSON text)
parser.NextObject As Map (when there is only one object in the json text)

```
private Sub ParseResponse (text As String) As List
parser.Initialize(text)
Private returnList As List
Private jsonMap As Map
Private jsonList As List

Try
    jsonList = parser.NextArray
    returnList = jsonList
    Return returnList
Catch
    Try
        jsonMap = parser.NextObject
        returnList.Add(jsonMap)
        Return returnList
    Catch
        Return Null     ' not a json text
    End Try
End Try
```

End Sub